# Padding differences between using form-horizontal and not using form-horizontal?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a layout using bootstrap and I noticed an odd padding in regards to using form-horizontal and not using it.

here is the code in question

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ddOrderType" class="control-label col-md-2">Order Type</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="ddOrderType" class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
      <label for="ddOrderType" class="control-label col-md-2">Zone</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="ddDiscountZone" class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this produces the image below that pops up in a new window, notice how the right side padding is different from the left side padding?

[image: Different padding]

Now if I remove the form-horizontal class, the padding on the left and right is equal and looks like this image below

[image: Equal Pdding]

What I don't like in this pic is that the labels aren't centered like they are in the form-horizontal pic, but the padding is equal.

So my question is why is the padding in the form-horizontal not equal on the left and right sides, but without using that class then the left and rights are equal and how do I fix the padding while using the form-horizontal on the right side so that it is equal with the left?

Comment: @Hopper, its just bootstrap. I don't have any custom css for this

Comment: The classname of the first div tag has a missing ". If this was copied from your original source, you might want to fix that

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason for the difference in "padding" is not actually the padding property. The labels have a width of 16.66% and are right aligned.
[image]

As you can see from the picture, I have highlighted the space occupied by the elements (red for labels, green for the divs).
In the second picture you provided, the text-align is back to left, so it gives the impression of the space being evenly distributed at that width

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a row class. Try this

```
<div class="form-horizontal>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ddOrderType" class="control-label col-md-2">Order Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="ddOrderType" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <label for="ddOrderType" class="control-label col-md-2">Zone</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="ddDiscountZone" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but only if i start resizing the window width.I was kind of expecting to not have to keep resizing the window until the padding equals eachother

Comment: Your markup seems correct. A fiddler to reproduce the issue would help